# The definition of the report is invalid

Tags: xml, rdlc, reportviewer

Trying to create an RDLC report but am running into an exception:

The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox40.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.  Here's the code:

```
                              <Value>
                                =Fields!TermsDescription.Value &amp; " " &amp; Fields!PrimaryCurrency.Value &amp; vbcrlf &amp;
                                iif((Parameters!DocType.Value = "INVOICE" and Fields!ShowInterestStatement.Value), "1.5% Per Month (19.56% per Annum)" &amp; vbcrlf &amp; "Will be Charged on Overdue Accounts" &amp; vbcrlf &amp;
                                IIF((Parameters!DocType.Value = "ORDER ACKNOWLEDGEMENT"), "All goods sold are subject to Apex Remington's terms and conditions of sale which are available for your review at http://www.apexdistribution.com/terms", "test") &amp;

                              </Value>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `FalsePart` of the first [IIf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx) function.

```
=IIf(
    Expression1,
    TruePart1 & IIf(Expression2, TruePart2, FalsePart2),
    FalsePart1
)
```